# Appending elements to DOM in a loop structure

Tags: javascript, dom

Once the page has been loaded, I would like to append an additional  element for each existing  elements on the page.

I tried something like this:

```
    var divs=document.getElementsByTagName('div');

    for(i=0;i<divs.length;i++){
        newDiv=document.createElement('div');
        divs[i].appendChild(newDiv);
    }
```

Just a warning this will actually **freezes the browser** because the divs variable is dynamic and divs.length just gets larger and larger each time the loop goes.

Is there a way to determine the number of tags when the DOM is normally loaded for the first time and have a chance to work with the elements statically.

I can't there of another solution so far.

Thanks so much. 
Dennis!

Comment: not the answer to your question but you should call `var newDiv` before the loop. Creating a variable without `var` makes a global variable.

Comment: not necessarily before the loop

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that DOM collections are [*live*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/glossary.html), and when the underlying document structure is changed, it will be reflected automatically on the collection, that's why when the `length` property is accessed it will contain a new length, a common approach is to *cache* the length before starting the loop:

```
var divs=document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for(var i = 0, len = divs.length;i<len;i++){
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    divs[i].appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

<sub>Also notice that you should declare all your variables with the `var` statement, otherwise it might become global.</sub>

**Edit:** In this case, since you are appending child nodes of the same tagName, the collection will be modified, and the indexes *will no longer match*, after the first iteration, the index `1` will refer to the `newDiv` object from the previous iteration, as [@Casey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198540/appending-elements-to-dom-in-a-loop-structure/3198624#3198624) recommends it will be safer to convert the collection to a plain array before traversing it.

I use the following function:

```
function toArray(obj) {
  var array = [];
  // iterate backwards ensuring that length is an UInt32
  for (var i = obj.length >>> 0; i--;) { 
    array[i] = obj[i];
  }
  return array;
}

//...
var divs = toArray(document.getElementsByTagName('div'));
//...
```

Comment: I didn't realize they were *live*. +1 for teaching me something new ;)

Comment: How does the live collection grow?  When you do divs[0].appendChild(newDiv), does newDiv appear in divs[1] or divs[divs.length-1]?  I'd feel safer by making an array of the original divs and then iterating over that, which is what Casey Hope suggested.

Comment: Does it only update when you access `length`? So if I append a child to element n, element n+1 will have the same index as before as long as I don't access `length`?

Comment: It should be added, that `divs` is an instance of `HtmlElementCollection`, not a plain array (as one could expect).

Comment: @Marius - `divs` will contain the div's in document order, so `newDiv` in your example will appear at `divs[1]`. @jasongetsdown - if it only got updated when accessing the length property, then that would be a bug. Also, I'm not sure if the DOM specs require implementors to use the exact names as in the spec such as `NodeList`, `HTMLCollection` etc, as long as they follow the exact interface. So `getElementsByTagName` must return an object that conforms to the [`NodeList`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-536297177) interface.

Answer (score 3):

Like you said, the `divs` variable is dynamic, so you have to convert it into an array (which is static) before you use it.

```
var nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var divs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++)
    divs.push(nodeList[i]);
// loop again and append the other divs
```

Another (more elegant) way to do this is:

```
var divs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('div'));
```

But alas, this method does not work in IE.

Answer (score 1):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), this is pretty straight forward.  You can get a reference to all the existing divs or any other element on the page and then append a new element very easily without needing to create an explicit loop.  Hope this help.

```
$('div').each(function(){
   var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
   $(this).append(newDiv);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName()` does **NOT** return a plain array, but an instance of `HtmlCollection`, which behaves like an array, but in fact presents some kind of view to all elements with the given element name in the document.

So, whenever you insert something into the DOM, the length property of `divs` will be updated too - of course.

So, besides other answers here, this behaviour should make sense now ;-)